# Sencha and codeigniter in mobile and web applications

Tags: codeigniter, extjs

I am developing a mobile version of an application using Sencha while another member of my group is developing the desktop/pc version using CodeIgniter. Is it possible that these two will work together? I'm looking for a way for these two versions to share the same models, controllers, etc. and the only thing that will be different is the css that is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible.

Just build REST Controller which returns data to Sencha.

Link: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/